# Can't form an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I encounter a problem while trying to form an object dynamically. errorKey should be a string which again forms dynamically. It can be for example

```
dispatch(stopSubmit("edit", { 'key': { 'tiny_error': data.messages[0] } }));
```

The problem is that compiler doesnt't see the variable errorKey at all. When hardcoded like is listed above, the code works as expected. But how to form an appropriate object dynamically?

```
    const errorMessage = data.messages[0];
    const errorKey = errorMessage.substring(0, errorMessage.length - 1));
    dispatch(stopSubmit("edit", { 'key': { errorKey: data.messages[0] } }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the syntax you're looking for is brackets around `errorKey`, like so:

```js
{ [errorKey]: data.messages[0] }
```

Comment: Indeed! Thank you)